# Endpoint cannot be resolved to a type (@Endpoint in ws)- Eclipse compilation error

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, ws

This is some what strange or may be i am missing something.

I am publishing an SOAP endpoint with Spring Boot application. Below is pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> ..................
<parent>
    .............
</parent>
<groupId>com.gd</groupId>
<artifactId>sl</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>sl</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> ..........plugin and other stuff.
```

As per the tutorials, we need only wsdl4j dependency to publish a SOAP endpoint.

Below is my endpoint class -

```
@Endpoint
public class UserDetailsEndpoint {

}
```

This is as simple as it could be, but eclipse is showing compilation error and do not resolve the @Endpoint annotation to

```
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
```

[image: Compilation error]

What could be the issue, What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Did you try updating your maven project? right click on project->maven->and update the project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws/spring-ws-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

An often successful way to find needed dependencies is to simply search "maven `<missing-package>`".

In this case I searched "maven `org.springframework.ws`" and found this dependency.

Comment: Well, it worked, but I did not understand where to search and what to search?

Comment: now compilation error is at EnableWs on configuration class.

Comment: I think I understood what you mean.  Thanks.